# What is wrong in this code

Tags: bash, unix

> Here i have got various inputs from keyboard and checked these validations

Book_id must be unique.
Subject code can only be either UNIX or C.The Shelll i work is bash

i got the following errors

./test.sh: line 5: declare: `=0': not a valid identifier
/test.sh: line 13: unix: command not found
./test.sh: line 92: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
    echo -n "Enter Book Accession number: "
        read Book_accession_number

        declare -a var_id
        declare -i i =0

        subject()
        {
        echo -n "Enter Subject code:"

        read Subject_code

        if ("$Subject_code" !=  "unix")
        then
{
        if ("$Subject_code"  !=  "c")
        then
{
        echo "please enter unix or c"
        subject
        }
        fi
}
        fi


        subject
        Book()
        {
        echo -n "Enter Book ID:"
        read Book_id
        echo -n "Enter Book Accession number: "
        read Book_accession_number

        declare -a var_id
        declare -i i =0






        while(j -ne i)
        {
        j++
        if(var_id[i]==Book_id)
        then
        {
        echo "please enter a unique id"
        Book
}
        fi


        }

        Book


        echo -n "Enter Author Name:"
        read Author_name

        echo -n "Enter Year of Publication:"

        read YOP

        echo -n "Enter Title of Book:"

        read TOB

        echo -n  "Enter Publisher's name:"

        read PUB_Name;

        echo -n "Enter Price: "
        read Price
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention which programming language you're writing this in.

Comment: Which shell does this tries to run on?

Comment: at first I thought it was bash, but the if statements are all screwed up for that..

Comment: try indenting the code, you'll see you're missing some braces. Also, if statements don't come with brackets in bash, use square brackets for what you're doing (that's actually a command in itself called test, but that's another story)

Comment: also you don't call a function using `Book()`, that's just for declaring the function, instead just do `Book`

Comment: This script would not run in any bash that i've encountered. Are you sure it's bash? Even if your login shell is bash, this script could be using another shell. Like #!/bin/ksh or whatever.

Comment: its sh and where to open braces for IF statement can u give a expamle for IF staement with braces

Comment: Use `if [[ $Subject_code" !=  "unix" ]]`. Note the spaces around the double brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have read a bash tutorial [like this one](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). It will help you to get used to the bash syntax.

Answer (score 1):

first one is no space should be placed between variable and = symbol. like x=0;

second one is in the IF conditions use the [] or (( )) instead of () symbol.

3rd one, i dont see any 92nd line in ur script. I suggest you to try putting a new line (empty line) after the last line of your code.

Comment: i m not able to solve this error ./test.sh: line 92: syntax error: unexpected end of file
 what should i do

Comment: hi arunachalam,

is that the whole code you are using? if so i cant see a 92nd line. 

however i found one more thing
in the function Book, chage the line declare -i i =0 to declare -i i=0 [ remove space before = sign]